# "REMOTE_ADDR" returning the same IP

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to figure out why I'm only being returned one IP address when call Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]. Here's my code:

```
var ip = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
        {
            ip = context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
        return ip;
```

I have about 22,000 records that return the same IP address. I've tested X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_CLIENT_IP locally only, and they both come up null. I'm wondering if any of you have any clue as to why this is happening? I'm basically trying to get a rough estimate of where the client is located.
Thanks.

Comment: How is browser communicating with your webserver? Is it behind load balancer, or maybe covered with CloudFlare?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the webserver is configured. It seems that if the remote address is always the same, maybe a reverse proxy is involved?

Comment: Typically its stored in `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` but since its not working you should do more research about the infrastructure I guess to see where the original address is lost (or stored).

Comment: Dump all the headers out to see if it is stored in a different one.